# Why is the process_time() giving me incorrect seconds?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I was expecting to have my model trained for no longer than 2 hrs but the result seemed to be longer if converted to hours. What could possible have gone wrong?

So here's my code to measure the time elapsed to train my mode:

```
from time import process_time
start = process_time()
history = model.fit(data,...)
end = process_time()
print(end - start)
```

The results were

```
end - start: 64871.5. 
end = 64888.703125 
start = 17.203125
```

I feel like it actually recorded the actual time itself (I remember running the training at around 17:00ish) but I may be wrong. I am expecting that it will give me the time in seconds. If that is the case, is there any way that I can convert the result into actual seconds elapsed?

Comment: Use `time.perf_counter` for accurate measure

Comment: `process_time()` returns the total amount of processor seconds consumed by the process. Your result seems consistent with running for a couple of hours on eight cores.

Comment: If you are running something that might take several hours, `time.time()` is likely fine.